# How to have numbers in a number input go up by hundreds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, here is what I want. I have an input box (type = number) and instead of having it go by ones, I would like it to go up by hundreds. I assume there is a way to do this. I know one way you could is a loop in JavaScript or JQuery that checks if it is 1 (and that equals 100) and then 101 = 200 etc. but that seems like the hard way to do things. Any suggestions? Here is some sample code:

HTML

```
<input type = "number" min = "100" value = "100">
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need for javascript.  Add `step="100"`:
`<input type="number" min="100" value="100" step="100" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`step`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp) attr for this:

> The step attribute specifies the legal number intervals for an  element.

```html
<input type="number" min="100" value="100" step="100">
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved easily using the step attribute
for example

`<input type = "number" min = "100" value = "100" step="100">`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the step attribute

```
 <input type="number" step="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type = "number" min = "100" value = "100" step="100">
```